# Scala: Accessing a variable declared inside a method in another method

Tags: scala

I have a private method where I'm declaring and defining a variable:

```
private def createDF() = {
   val df = spark.read.avro("fileA")
}
```

How can I access this val df from another method in the same class?

Comment: You can't. `df` is created with every invocation of `createDF()` and destroyed **after** every invocation of `createDF()`. You would have to declare it as a `private var` outside of `createDF()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, variables declared in a function have the function scope and are only visible inside the function.

If you want to reuse the variable, you need to set it as a class variable:

```
class MyClass {
  private var df: Option[DataFrame] = None

  private def createDF() = {
    this.df = Some(spark.read.avro("fileA"))
  }
  def otherFunction() = {
    this.df.map(df => ...)
  }
}
```

I use `Option` here to avoid `NullPointerException`s that may arrive when using `null` if the variable is not yet initialized

Answer (score -1):

You can't access `df` from `otherFunction` as it is declared at the scope of `createDF`. I would change it something like this.

```
def createDF() = {
  spark.read.avro("fileA")
}

def otherFunction(create: () => DataFrame) = {
  val df = create()
  ...
}
```

And call `otherFunction` as `otherFunction(createDF)`. Another approach using implicits...

```
implicit val df = createDF()

def otherFunction(implicit df: DataFrame) = {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't really think this is a good use for implicits. If you start declaring implicit dataframes, it will get confusing trying to figure out which one was passed to which method.

Comment: The question had just one Dataframe. And yes I agree, if you have multiple, then it will be confusing definitely, difficult to track.

Comment: The question has just one DataFrame, but it's likely the actual code has more. So I take issue with an answer that recommends using implicits here and claims using implicits like this is "better." Please remove that part.